# How can I debug why simplest MySQL query returns false?

Tags: php, mysql

I work with xampp. I performed MySQL connection:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($host , $user , $passw);
mysql_select_db($db, $connection);
```

I received output with echo command (by check the boolean returned values) that connection is established and the database $db is found.

But the simplest query like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users'");
```

returns false. How can I debug why?Thanks.

Comment: Did u try to run query in phpmyadmin or database you are using ?

Comment: @ashes999 Thanks for an idea. I tried it right now and still I receives return $query = false.

Comment: -0.25 for still using `mysql_query`.

Comment: @Milap Yes, I tried also now and it works fine in phpadmin.

Comment: @Marcus Adams  The "SELECT 1" also returns false. But I tried now also with `` , still $query = false.

Comment: @cHao  What do you mean?

Comment: @tatiana_c: I mean that with mysqli and PDO in existence, the mysql extension is outdated. If it's not deprecated yet, it should be -- it's barely supported anymore. Take a look at mysqli -- in the simple cases it works like mysql, but when you finally learn that everything w3schools or whatever taught you is wrong, you can easily switch to using prepared statements and the OO interface bit by bit with very little trouble. (As opposed to having to also switch everything from `mysql_query` to something else entirely, cause the mysql extension has no support whatsoever for prepared statements.)

Comment: @MarcusAdams Finally I found the error. It should be also parameter $connection into mysql_query command.

Comment: @cHao I still don't understand what I can write instead of it. I will be glad to learn something more modern. Can you please put some link to any site that show example or explain this topic? Thanks.

Comment: @tatiana_c: [My profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/319403/chao) has an example using PDO.  The PHP manual of course has sections on [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @cHao Thanks for the links.I read some sections there and it looks great.I didn't heard about something like it before. But I miss something. With which database it works? I mean that for run mysql commands I need a mysql program. Where data that interact with PDO are saved?

Comment: @tatiana_c: PDO connects to MySQL, PostgreSQL, DB2...pretty much any database system it has drivers for, which is a bunch.  (The DSN you use to connect tells it which database to use.)  Mysqli is the new hotness re: MySQL, and connects just to it.  Major plus for mysqli: til you're ready to make the change, you can use it almost exactly like you use the mysql_ functions now (just with the `$link` param typically first rather than last), and you'll still have access to most of the new spiff (like prepared statements).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**An obligatory update**: as mysql ext is no more, here are answers for two remaining MySQL APIs which I written on my site based on the experience from answering 1000s questions on Stack Overflow:

- [How to report errors in mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting)
- [How to connect to MySQL using PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql) (with the aim of the proper error reporting).

In short, for mysqi the following line have to be added before `mysqli_connect()` call:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

while for PDO the proper error mode have to be set, for example

```
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

As of the old mysql ext,

To get an error from `mysql_query()` you have to use `mysql_error()` function.
So always run all your queries this way, at least until you develop a more advanced query handler:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'users'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$query);
```

the problem with your current query is `'users'` part. Single quotes have to be used to delimit strings while for the identifiers you have to use backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
```

In order to see these errors during development, add these lines at the top of your code to be sure you can see every error occurred

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

on the production server, however, the value on the first line should be changed from 1 to 0

Comment: It's great. It gives me the errors. I see for now that database is not selected. This is exactly command that I looked for. Thanks!

Comment: mysql_* functions are removed in PHP 7. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: @knt5784 thank you, I added alternatives for PDO and mysqli

Answer (score 4):

Use the mysql_error() function:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users'") or die(mysql_error());
```

EDIT: Per Col. Shrapnel's comment: you should never use die() outside of a test environment. In general it's bad practice when writing code that's even intended for production.

Here is some more information: http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die

Comment: Never use die(). That's extremely bad practice.

Comment: In a production environment I would completely agree, but this seems to clear be a test environment. Still, thanks for the comment and I'll clarify it in the answer.

Comment: you are using different codes on the development and production? Really you are?

Comment: In case you're wondering why, `die(mysql_error())` shows the MySQL error to the end user, which, besides being user unfriendly, is also a potential security risk.

Comment: Anyway, how it is supposed to track errors on the production?

Comment: Depends. If I am testing something that I haven't worked with before, like the user who asked this question clearly is doing, then I would definitely write some simple scripts in a 100% test environment before starting from scratch with something intended for production.

Comment: You still fail to answer the production error tracking question. I doubt you have the answer at all.

Comment: Personally I usually don't track MySQL errors in production sites, instead giving a generic message that there is a problem. It's not usually the best way, but it works very well for me for reasons I won't go into here. Keep in mind that nowhere did I say that there was anything wrong with your answer to use trigger_error(), which is indeed a good idea.

Comment: You are sharing very common delusion, mixing error *tracking* with error *reporting*. On the production errors have to be *logged* and that's vital for the any site of whatever importance. Logged, to be reviewed by the programmer/webmaster who is otherwise unable to make idea of what's going on on the site. What's why trigger_error() have to be used - it will follow site-wide error-reporting settings, keeps you informed either on the dev or prod. Without any changes in the code. And, just to let you know, **nobody**, **never** reads remarks. But only copy the code. So,be careful with the code

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619635/3377046) answer this is an object oriented style:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'users'";
$result = $mysqli -> query($query) or trigger_error($mysqli -> error." ".$query);
```