# Basic PHP/MYSQL debugging

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still new to php and this is what I've come up with after looking at many tutorials online. I have a basic submit form and I just want to store the data in the database. When I submit it and I check my database, there's nothing there.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">     
Value1: <input type="text" name="field1-name" />

<input type="Submit" /></form>
```

And the php file:

```
<?php 
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "db";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

$field1-name =  mysqli_real_escape_string ( $conn , $_POST['field1-name'])

$sql = "INSERT INTO db (APP_NAME)
VALUES ('$field1-name')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug why simplest MySQL query returns false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619610/how-can-i-debug-why-simplest-mysql-query-returns-false)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong here.

Firstly, this variable is invalid `$field1-name`.

PHP is interpreting that as doing math, such as "field1 MINUS name".

Use an underscore `$field1_name` and for all instances for it in your code.

and use error reporting.

Sidenote:

- Use `mysqli_affected_rows()`.
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

in order to be 100% sure of a successful query/insert and in conjunction with your error checking.

It's better than `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)` but that's a matter of preference I guess.

You also have a missing semi-colon in

```
$field1-name =  mysqli_real_escape_string ( $conn , $_POST['field1-name'])
                                                                          ^ right there
```

which error reporting would have caught as a parse error.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Footnotes:

To ensure that your field isn't empty, use `empty()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

I.e.: `if(!empty($_POST['field1-name'])){...}`

The `!` means "not", as in "if not empty".

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

The real reason this script is failing to record anything into the database is because at line 7, you have a line of code that tells the script to die if there is an error in the database connection:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
```

But what if the connection was successful?  We look for the *CLOSING BRACES* for the `if ($conn->connect_error)` statement, which is found at line 22:

```
    }
?>
```

But instead of doing things that should happen if the connection is successful, this script ends immediately after the closing brace to the code block for the `if ($conn->connect_error)` statement.  In other words, nothing happens.

### The Fix

Remove the closing bracket at line 22, below the `$conn->close();` statement; and place it instead immediately after the `die();` statement.

Next, fix a few syntax errors:

1. You need a semicolon after the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` statement.
2. Don't use '-' (dashes or minus signs) in variable names.  Remove them or replace them with the more conventional underscore character (_).
3. Your SQL syntax is incorrect.  Try something like this:

   `$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name ('APP_NAME') VALUES ('".$field1."')";`

   Because you have already connected to your desired database (`$dbname = "db";`), SQL only needs to know the *table* to use within that database.  Replace `table_name` from my example as appropriate.  It'll be the table with a column called `APP_NAME` where it appears you want to store the form's post data.  Finally, for the `VALUES()`, it is best to use the `('".$field1."')` format rather than `('$field1')` because it is more explicit.  The latter will cause you problems under certain circumstances.

My rewrite of your code looks like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "db";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
    $field1 =  mysqli_real_escape_string ( $conn , $_POST['field1']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name ('APP_NAME') VALUES ('".$field1."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```