# MySQL "UPDATE" not working?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

So I have the following code, I have made sure that both the variables have something stored in them, by echoing the results in both `$lat` and `$long`

```
    $lat = $latitude;
    $updatelat = mysql_query("UPDATE listings SET lat='". $lat ."' WHERE id='". $id ."'");
    $long = $longitude;
    $updatelong = mysql_query("UPDATE listings SET long='". $long ."' WHERE id='". $id ."'");
```

The `$updatelat` query works absolutely perfect, and the value is set in the database.

The `$updatelong` query however **doesn't** work, but there is definitely a value stored in `$long`

Can anyone see something obviously wrong with this code? There is definitely a column called `long` in my database. I am completely confused.

Comment: add your create statement of the table

Comment: I don't have that to hand. The 'lat' and 'long' columns are both TEXT.

Comment: sienote: stop using deprecated mysql_* functions! and start using pdo or mysqli to have a higher security (better prevention to sqlinjections)

Comment: id might be integer which you are providing as string

Comment: I'm not asking for advice on whether I should stop using mysql_ functions, I'm asking for a solution to my problem, @davejal.

Comment: @raheelshan So why would the first query work perfectly then?

Comment: Do you get an error, do you have your debugging on?

Comment: What's the value in `$long`? You might have an escaping issue.

Comment: try this one `mysql_query("UPDATE listings SET lat='". $latitude ."',long='". $longitude ."' WHERE id=$id");`

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax I've just realized all the values in $long have `-` and then the string. So for example, `$long = -3.012354`... does the `-` have any effect on the query?

Comment: with debugging you would have found the answer to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9619610/3664960) it might help next time.

Comment: @davejal all the `$long` values SHOULD include `-`, for most cases anyway. They are co-ordinates

Comment: You can avoid escaping/quoting/etc. issues by using prepared statements, although that would mean you'd have to stop using the `mysql_*` api (which you should do anyway because it's deprecated in PHP5 and gone from PHP7. ;) )

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Thanks for the advice, I will update at some point, but let's say for instance I don't have time at the moment to update everything to mysqli. Is there a workaround for now, still using `mysql_*`?

Comment: You could try passing `$lat` and `$long` through [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: That's not the point I was trying to make, just trying to give you positive feedback even thought you already have you're answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix for this

If queries such as this don't work:

```
$updatelat = mysql_query("UPDATE listings SET lat='". $lat ."' WHERE id='". $id ."'");
```

There is probably a clash with MySQL reserved keywords, so try using backticks

```
$updatelat = mysql_query("UPDATE listings SET `lat`='". $lat ."' WHERE `id`='". $id ."'");
```

and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Why 2 queries? You can do it in one as the id is same.

```
$lat = $latitude;
$long = $longitude;
$updatelatlong = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE listings SET lat='". $lat ."',long='". $long ."' WHERE id='". $id ."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you do this `$result = mysqli_query($con,$updatelong);` ? It'd be helpfull to see more of your code than this little part