# Problems with foreach PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```html
<?php
include('../../../config.php');

 for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['theID']);$i++) {

  $id = $_POST['theID'][$i];

  mysql_query("UPDATE ava_users SET about = '$id' WHERE id = '$id'");

 } 
?>
```

I have a select multiple option form that has an $_POST output of: 2,3 for an example. The 2,3 are ID's I have selected for user's IDs.

Id like to use ID's 2,3 and add them into a MySQL_query() such as,

MySQL_query("INSERT INTO... WHERE ID = 2);

MySQL_query("INSERT INTO... WHERE ID = 3);

etc..

I have tried this snippet code and seems to be not working...

Can anyone help?

Comment: You *should* switch from `mysql_*` as it has been [officially](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) deprecated. Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) **with** [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Do you get any [errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619610/how-can-i-debug-why-simplest-mysql-query-returns-false) when the snippet didn't work?

Comment: Take a piece of paper, yes a non digital piece of paper!, and write exactly down what values your have in each iteration of your for loop: `for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['theID']);$i++)`. Also make sure to do: `print_r($_POST["theID"]);` once and compare it with the numbers you use in `$_POST['theID'][$i]`

Comment: I don't get any errors as its ran threw ajax.

Comment: @Veasey let the [console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) be the judge of that!

Comment: I know I am being picky but `for` =/= `foreach`

Comment: *"I have tried this snippet code and seems to be not working"* what do you expect it to do? what is it doing instead?

Comment: For Example:

<?php 
$the_id = '2,3';

 for ($i=0;$i<count($the_id);$i++) {

  echo $the_id[$i];

 } 
 ?>

Only shows 2. Not 2 then 3.

Comment: @Script47 =/= = not equal

Comment: @Veasey Do what I said in my last comment and take your time. Maybe even take a little break so you don't look at it all the time.

Comment: in your example $the_id = '2,3'; is incorrect, you can't loop inside this data because is not an array, really you get an array in your POST ?

Comment: You had better show us you HTML for this form. It will make it clear what you have done in the HTML and therefore what you should be expecting in the PHP

Answer (score 1):

As I underatand, the POST string is a list of ids, separated by commas. You need to get clean array of ids, not a string.
For that purpose, use

`$ids = explode(",", $_POST["theID"]);`

Then, iterate through that array like you did before:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++)
{ 
    $id = $ids[$i];
    mysql_query("UPDATE ava_users SET about = '$id' WHERE id = '$id'"); 
}
```

Comment: Il give this a try.

Comment: i was about to leave a comment about that when the OP commented on the example input of `$the_id`

Comment: You really, really, really want to escape those values.

Comment: @tadman and they really, really, really, really, really, really need to use something other than mysql_*

Comment: Still did not work, il show you my AJAX:

function ShareGame(id, site_url) {
 $('#report_submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");
 theIDs = $('#the_id').val();
 $.ajax({
  url: SITE_URL+"/includes/view_game/ajax/share_game.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: "theID="+theIDs+"&id="+id,
  success: function(data) {
   $('#report_submit').removeAttr("disabled");
   HidePopup();
  }
 });
}

Comment: AND HTML/PHP:
    <select name="the_id[]" multiple>

    <?php

     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ava_friends WHERE user1 = $user[id] ORDER BY user2 asc");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {    

     $friend = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ava_users WHERE id = $row[user2]"));

     echo '<option id="the_id" value="'.$friend['id'].'">'.$friend['username'].'</option>';

     }

    ?>

    </select>

Comment: @Veasey You have to get out of the habit of just dumping variables in your queries. That won't work. PHP doesn't interpolate strings that way.

Comment: @Veasey You have to get out of the habit of just dumping your code in the comments. That won't help.

Comment: Love it when they (OP's) drop code into comments, then the plot keeps on getting thicker, and thicker and thicker. Then people keep getting chased down rabbit holes, deeper and deeper and deeper.

Comment: @tadman Given the question, the lack of code (dropping into comments I might add), Daniel's doing his best to help this guy (or gal). I'd of never been chased down that rabbit hole. Not by that waskiwee wabbit; oooohhh no siree mister.